# How can i make a two symbols expression in my regex (!=)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I'm trying to write a regex in order to split a string like that : `"name = John"` become an array `["name", "=", "John"]`

My problem is that i can't find how i can do the same thing with `!=` or `<=` using a regex.

My regex : `/(?=[=<>])|(?<=[=<>])/gm`

Anyone has an idea ? Thanks !

Comment: `"name = John".split(" ")` ?

Comment: Or, `text.split(/\W+/)`.

Comment: I think the OP looks more for something like [`'name != John'.split(/\s*(!==|===|!=|==|<=|>=|=|<|>)\s*/)`](https://regex101.com/r/aurhqh/1/)

Comment: I forget to precise I need to keep the operator (in my case !=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thank you Peter Seliger that's what i was searching for :)

Answer : `'name != John'.split(/\s*(!==|===|!=|==|<=|>=|=|<|>)\s*/)`

Comment: did you figure out what the pattern does express and why it does work with split exactly the way you are looking for?

Comment: Well, i think so, in your case you are searching for the exact syntax so it'll work fine.

Comment: ... not quite ... the real trick is done by the capture group `( ... )`. Used for splitting a string, the captured characters are also part of the resulting array. And in this special case the whitespaces before and after the group are part of the split expression but not part of the result. Thus such whitespace sequences are stripped from the result.